# How do I pass in my publishable key to the stripe_payment Flutter plugin?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, static, stripe-payments

I am having an issue with getting the stripe_payment 1.0.7 flutter plugin to work for my app. I have set up the relevant code as follows

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    StripeService.payWithNewCard();
  },
  child: Text(
    'Pay with Credit Card'
  ),
),
```

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:stripe_payment/stripe_payment.dart';


class StripeService {

  static init() {
    StripePayment.setOptions(
      StripeOptions(
        publishableKey: "pk_test_x6emjIeRejVh1qhghRpMHxpe00GQXfxIHz",
        merchantId: "Test",
        androidPayMode: 'test',
      ),
    );
  }

  static Future<String> payWithNewCard() async {
    try {
      var paymentMethod = await StripePayment.paymentRequestWithCardForm(
        CardFormPaymentRequest(),
      );
      return 'Success';
    } catch (err) {
      return 'Transaction failed: ${err.toString()}';
    }
  }
}
```

However, on my application, whenever I try to submit a credit card I get this API key error message:
[ios Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyPNY.png)

I am pretty sure the error happens when the CardFormPaymentRequest() method is called because I get this error message to pop up after I have inputted my credit card info and hit "done".

It was working not too long ago and I was sending transaction data to Stripe, but today this error message popped up again. Do you know what could be wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your public key is right? is looks quite small.check again, just in case

Comment: Yes, I just double-checked, the public key is correct. I feel like when I call StripePayment.paymentRequestWithCardForm( CardFormPaymentRequest() ); it is not recognizing the StripeOptions() I set in the init() method.

Comment: (Since you implied that it was working before) how about generating a new token?

Comment: according to ios error there is problem with either public or secret key

Comment: Also, provide console or debug mode statements

Comment: Hello, I just generated a new token but it still shows the same error. The only thing I can find in the console is a single closing bracket (as seen below...)Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device iPhone 11 Pro Max...
Reloaded 7 of 690 libraries in 299ms.
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what was wrong. The init method on the class StripeService was never being called. It had gotten deleted somehow its subclass which called and used it. When I placed the following code back within the widget which called StripeService, everything went back to working as expected. Thank you!

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  StripeService.init();
}
```